# Nginx Multiple Location Blocks

Tags: nginx, nginx-location

Experts,

This is very weird and I have spent good 5 hrs pulling my hair to understand what is wrong in the below configurations.

With the below configuration I expect the request to be handled by the respective location blocks however all my request are handled by the **location /** block only.

Any advice?

```
# For more information on configuration, see:
#   * Official English Documentation: http://nginx.org/en/docs/
#   * Official Russian Documentation: http://nginx.org/ru/docs/

user nginx;
worker_processes auto;
error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;
pid /run/nginx.pid;

# Load dynamic modules. See /usr/share/doc/nginx/README.dynamic.
include /usr/share/nginx/modules/*.conf;

events {
    worker_connections 1024;
}

http {
    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    sendfile            on;
    tcp_nopush          on;
    tcp_nodelay         on;
    keepalive_timeout   65;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;

    include             /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type        application/octet-stream;

    # Load modular configuration files from the /etc/nginx/conf.d directory.
    # See http://nginx.org/en/docs/ngx_core_module.html#include
    # for more information.
    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;

    server {
        listen       80 default_server;
        listen       [::]:80 default_server;
        server_name  _;
        #root         /usr/share/nginx/html;

        # Load configuration files for the default server block.
        include /etc/nginx/default.d/*.conf;

        location / {
                alias /var/www/projects/projectname/clientui/whatsupclientui/build/;
                index  index.html index.htm;
                try_files $uri /index.html;
        }

        location /organization/ {
                alias /var/www/projects/projectname/orgui/whatsuporgui/build/;
                index  index.html index.htm;
                try_files $uri /index.html;
        }

        location /api/admin/ {
                alias /var/www/projects/projectname/api/projectnameapis/build/;
                index  index.html index.htm;
                try_files $uri /index.html;
        }

        location /api/ {
                proxy_pass http://localhost:1337/;
        }

        #error_page 404 /404.html;
        #    location = /40x.html {
        #}

        #error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
        #    location = /50x.html {
        #}
    }

# Settings for a TLS enabled server.
#
#    server {
#        listen       443 ssl http2 default_server;
#        listen       [::]:443 ssl http2 default_server;
#        server_name  _;
#        root         /usr/share/nginx/html;
#
#        ssl_certificate "/etc/pki/nginx/server.crt";
#        ssl_certificate_key "/etc/pki/nginx/private/server.key";
#        ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:1m;
#        ssl_session_timeout  10m;
#        ssl_ciphers PROFILE=SYSTEM;
#        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
#
#        # Load configuration files for the default server block.
#        include /etc/nginx/default.d/*.conf;
#
#        location / {
#        }
#
#        error_page 404 /404.html;
#            location = /40x.html {
#        }
#
#        error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
#            location = /50x.html {
#        }
#    }

}
```

for this configuration any request to **/organization/** is still being honoured by **/** location block only

Update II:

Attached the debug logs for /organization/

[image]

Comment: request example? full configuration - what's there in server directive?

Comment: Use `nginx -T` (uppercase `T`) to view the entire configuration across all included files, and ensure that these `location` blocks are in the `server` block that handles the request. Use the access log and error log to understand the series of requests being processed by your server. Use `curl -I` to fire single requests at your server to breakdown a chain of responses.

Comment: [02/May/2021:09:36:53 +0000] "GET /qps/admin HTTP/1.1" 304 0 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/ - this is one shuch recored request from access log

Comment: Switch the error log in debug mode (https://nginx.org/en/docs/debugging_log.html) - you will see exactly why this location block is chosen.

Answer (score 2):

This is how it is supposed to be configured.

```
        location / {
                alias /var/www/projects/projectname/clientui/whatsupclientui/build/;
                index  index.html index.htm;
                try_files $uri /index.html;
        }

        location /organization/ {
                alias /var/www/projects/projectname/orgui/whatsuporgui/build/;
                index  index.html index.htm;
                #try_files $uri /index.html;
        }

        location /api/admin/init {
                proxy_pass http://localhost:1337/;
        }

        location /api/admin {
                alias /var/www/projects/projectname/api/projectnameapis/build/;
                index  index.html index.htm;
                #try_files $uri /index.html;
        }

        location /api/ {
                proxy_pass http://localhost:1337/;
        }
```